# Flask Application Not Running Properly: Issues with Environment and Dependencies specifically dotenv

Tags: python, flask, dotenv, python-dotenv

Issues:

When I run flask run, I get an error:

```
from dotnev import load_dotenv, dotenv_values
```

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dotnev'.
```

I'm unable to import the dotenv module: `Import "dotenv" could not be resolved Pylance (reportMissingImports)`.

Steps Taken:

```
    Recreated the virtual environment.
    Verified package versions in the virtual environment. using pip freeze. It has been found "python-dotenv==1.0.0"
    Checked the Flask application structure.
    Ensured correct usage of .env and .env.secret files.
    Used python-dotenv to load environment variables.
    Tried different interpreters for python, it causees a mess and doesn't fix it
```

Pieces of code:

```
    from dotenv import load_dotenv, dotenv_values


    config = dotenv_values("env.secret")
```

Installed packages:

```
    bcrypt==4.0.1
    blinker==1.6.3
    cffi==1.16.0
    click==8.1.7
    colorama==0.4.6
    cryptography==41.0.5
    Flask==3.0.0
    itsdangerous==2.1.2
    Jinja2==3.1.2
    MarkupSafe==2.1.3
    pycparser==2.21
    PyMySQL==1.1.0
    python-decouple==3.8
    python-dotenv==1.0.0
    setuptools==68.2.2
    Werkzeug==3.0.1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am hoping that dotenv can work one way or another.

Here is the file structure

```
project_folder

    pycache
    node_modules
    static
    templates
    venv
    .envsecret
    app.py
    launch.json
    package-lock.json
    package.json
    Readme.txt
    settings.json
    test.py
```

Comment: what is your structure files?

Comment: What version of pylance are you using?

Comment: I tried swapping to a different version and it did not do much. I am on pylance v2023.11.10 currently @ewokx

Comment: @TanThien Update the question to include the file structure

Comment: Check which python binary you're running flask with.  Make sure it's the same virutalenv that dotenv is installed in.

Comment: @ewokx just double checked they appeared to be, would there be anything else to check?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what fixed it but it started working. I rebooted the machine a couple of times. Didn't work on the project for awhile. Switched python interpreters a couple of times. Checked the locations of python, flask, and dotenv. I am very puzzled.